# How to copy local cached jars to a folder via SBT?

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I want to copy all the jars specified in the libraryDependencies to be copy to a folder in a task.

For example, I have the following dependencies defined for the project.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % neo4j_version,
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.8.0",
  "org.scala-lang" %% "scala-pickling" % "0.9.1",
  "org.neo4j.test" % "neo4j-harness" % neo4j_version % "test",
  "org.neo4j.driver" % "neo4j-java-driver" % "1.0.4" % "test"
)
```

Now I want to create a task so that every time I run the task, it will copy the jars in the dependencies to a folder.

I know I can manually specify the absolute paths for the jars to copy. I want a task that can automatically derive the paths to the jars. So later when I add a new dependency, I do not need to find the path in .ivy cache again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use managedClasspath to figure this out. See below for an example.

```
val copyJarsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("copy-jars", "Copys jars")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" %% "scala-pickling" % "0.9.1"
)

copyJarsTask := {
  val folder = new File("my-jars")

  (managedClasspath in Compile).value.files.foreach { f =>
    IO.copyFile(f, folder / f.getName)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [sbt-native-packager plugin with the Java Archetype](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/index.html#usage) and run:

```
sbt stage
```

The result will be that all your application dependencies and the JAR or the application itself will end up in the `target/universal/stage/lib/` directory.